# Holomorphic functions with equal inverse images of unit circle

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f,g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and have the property $f^{-1}(S)=g^{-1}(S)$ where S is the unit circle centered at 0. What can be said about $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exhaustive study of this question is contained in the paper

MR0825840
Stephenson, Kenneth
Analytic functions sharing level curves and tracts. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 123 (1986), no. 1, 107–144 (freely available online).